# Should my object be responsible for randomizing its own content?

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design, factory, builder

I'm building an app that generates random sequences of musical notes and displays them to the user as musical notation. These sequences can be generated according to several parameters, including density and maximum consecutive notes of the same pitch.

Musical sequences are captured by a `sequence` object whose `notes` property is a simple string of notes such as `"abcdaba"`.

My early attempts to generate random sequences involved a `SequenceGenerator` class that compiled random sequences using several private methods. This looks like a service to me. But I'm trying to honour the principle expressed in Domain-Driven Design (Evans 2003) to only use services where necessary and to prefer associating behaviour with domain objects.

So my question is:

**Should the job of producing random sequences be taken care of by a public method on `sequence` itself (such as `generateRandom()`) or should it be kept separate?**

I considered the possibility that my original design is more along the lines of a builder or factory pattern than a service, but the the code is very different for creating a random sequence than for creating one with a supplied string of notes.

One concern I have with the method route is that `generateRandom()` as a method on `sequence` changes the *content* of sequence but isn't actually generating a new sequence object. This just feels wrong, but I can't express why.

I'm still getting my head around some the core OO design principles, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Should the job of producing random sequences be taken care of by a public method on sequence itself (such as generateRandom()) or should it be kept separate?

I usually find that I get cleaner designs if I treat "random" the same way that I treat "time", or "I/O" -- as an input to the model, rather than as an aspect of the model itself.

> If you don't consider time an input value, think about it until you do -- it is an important concept ([John Carmack, 1998](http://archives.seul.org/linuxgames/Oct-1998/msg00123.html)).

Within the constraints of DDD, that could either mean passing a "domain service" as an argument to your method, allowing your aggregate to invoke the service as needed, or it could mean having a method on the aggregate, so that the application can pass in random numbers when needed.

> So any creation of a sequence would involve passing in some pattern or seed, but whether that is random or not is decided outside of the sequence itself?

Yes, exactly.

Comment: So any creation of a sequence would involve passing in some pattern or seed, but whether that is random or not is decided outside of the sequence itself?

Comment: Whether a randomized process generates a sequence of notes or a human is hand-picking a series of notes, the "sequence" concept is the same. I most likely wouldn't even put a `randomize(): Sequence` method on the `Sequence` itself if the goal was to randomize a new sequence from an existing one, given the responsibility of randomizing is not inherent to what a `Sequence` is. It is rather rare, but I think `Sequence` is a concept that will most likely end up void of behaviors given there are tons of operations you may want to perform with a sequence. E.g. playing a sequence, statistics, etc.

Comment: @voiceofunreason Do you think it's a good idea to have `sequence.play(player)`, etc. even if `player.play(sequence)` could be done without `Sequence` having knowledge it can be played, just for the sake of making it easy to find what operations can be performed with a sequence?

Comment: No - I believe that a code base should have one consistent heuristic that can be used to guess from `sequence.play(player)`, `player.play(sequence)`, `play(player, sequence)` ....  But that's an uninformed opinion -- I don't have enough experience with the motivating problem to claim any insights about your proposed solution.

Comment: @plalx I agree that the `sequence` should be void behaviours for the reason you state. There are so many ways to manipulate a sequence depending what it's used for and it shouldn't care about that (and, for the record, I favour `player.play(sequence)` as a heuristic). That's why I thought a `SequenceFactory` or `SequenceBuilder` could take care of the creation of a random sequence, making use of something like a `RandomNotesGenerator`.

Answer (score 0):

The creation of an object  is not usually considered part of the logic for the object.

How you do that technically is a different matter. You could potentially use delegation. For example:

```java
public interface NoteSequence {
    void play();
}

public final class LettersNoteSequence implements NoteSequence {
    public LettersNoteSequence(String letters) {
       ...
    }
    ...
}

public final class RandomNoteSequence implements NoteSequence {
    ...
    @Override
    public void play() {
       new LetterNoteSequence(generateRandomLetters()).play();
    }
}
```

This way you don't have to have a "service" or a "factory", but this is only one alternative, may or may not fit your use-case.

Comment: The question then becomes: how does generateRandomLetters() figure in the domain? Is it a method of a class `RandomLetterGenerator`? This is an option. But in this case, the letters being generated share not arbitrary: they are created to be used in a sequence, so there is an implicit coupling there. This is why I first thought of them as a method on the sequence.

Comment: Yes, the `generateRandomLetters()` is then in the `RandomNoteSequence`. The requirements wanted a random note sequence, so the semantic coupling comes from the "business". It is not incidental, therefore it is ok.

Comment: Yes I see. This is a decent way to wrap the randomisation for the random sequences